# IE displays flash movie with wrong height using swfobject

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, internet-explorer

I have a full screen flash movie that loads and displays correctly in firefox and chrome. In IE, however, it displays at 1/3 the width. The embedded code is relatively simple:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="/javascripts/swfobject.js?1331841761" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       //<![CDATA[
swfobject.embedSWF('/bin/SglWeb.swf','flashContent','100%','100%','11.0.0','/expressInstall.swf',{},{},{});
     //]]>
   </script>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="flashContent">
      <p><a href="https://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="https://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I change:

```
swfobject.embedSWF('/bin/SglWeb.swf','flashContent','100%','100%','11.0.0','/expressInstall.swf',{},{},{});
```

to

```
swfobject.embedSWF('/bin/SglWeb.swf','flashContent','1024','768','11.0.0','/expressInstall.swf',{},{},{});
```

IE respects the height, but I would really like to use 100% height. What could I be doing wrong?

Tested in IE 8, Windows XP, Flash Player 11, SWFObject v2.0

Comment: 2 things I would try (no answer directly though) setting a background color on the div to determine if the div is sized incorrectly or just the embedded component, if you see the div is sized incorrectly attempt to change the width on the div itself, the second thing I would try if the first failed is upgrading to the latest swfobject 2.2

Comment: press f12 & see what is bieng rendered...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but swfobject replaces the div with the <object/> code so any style I add to the div is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have encountered the annoying hasLayout problem in IE.  Because your div doesn't specify a height, and your flash movie has a height of 100%, IE is stumped and reverting to a default height (I think it's in the 300px range).  [This is a good article on hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).  You may try something like adding display:inline-block or min-height:anyvalue  to your container div to force hasLayout on IE and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply Heather. Unfortunately none of the hacks  you mentioned worked. I'll keep reading your link and keep trying other approaches and I'll let you know the result.

Comment: Are you still using height:100%?  Have you tried setting the height of the flash movie (for testing purposes)?

Comment: You were right. The trick is that swfobject replaces the div instead of embedding it inside. I had to instruct swfobject to add this behaviour: `swfobject.embedSWF('/bin/SglWeb.swf','flashContent','100%','100%','10.0.0','/expressInstall.swf',{},{},{style: "width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute"});`

Comment: Wow, really!  That is frustrating, that swfobject would actually replace an html tag.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution to this problem: My rails 3 server was automatically adding the following HTTP Header:

```
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

Which changed IE's 8 behaviour. I removed it and it also solved the problem. Lot of details to keep in mind when working with IE :/

Comment: Wow!  Good catch there!  My mantra is "anything that looks cool on the interwebs will surely NOT work in IE"